# .Net: Data Layer Caching with Multiple Interfaces

Tags: .net, caching

I have a project of business objects and a data layer that could potentially be implemented in multiple interfaces (web site, web services, console app, etc).

My question deals with how to properly implement caching in the methods dealing with data retrieval.  I'll be using SqlCacheDependency to determine when the cached objects need to be expired, but I'm unsure of the best way of implementing the cache itself:

If the library is being used for a web project, I'd like to use HttpRuntime.Cache; however, I'm guessing that would be an issue for console apps.

What is the best way of implementing caching in your data layer for a .Net project when allowing for multiple types of interfaces like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .net 4.0 you should look into the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) in the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) namespace. This was added into .net 4.0 specifically to address the fact that non-ASP.NET applications had no caching API, or had to ship with a dependency on System.Web and use HttpRuntime.Cache. Alternatively you could look into AppFabric caching, which is client-agnostic but may entail overhead you don't want to have to deal with.

If you're on an earlier version of .net then you might find the easiest way is to bite the bullet and take the dependency on System.Web, then you can use HttpRuntime.Cache everywhere - it's not a perfect solution but it has the virtue of consistency. An alternative would be to look at the [Enterprise Library Caching Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx), which again is client-agnostic but is not recommended for use in web apps where the HttpRuntime stuff is available.

Comment: I just realized the SqlCacheDependency class is in System.Web, so it looks like in this situation I'll need it regardless; I was just concerned with whether the HttpRuntime.Cache would work outside of IIS, but it sounds like it will.  Now i'll just need to determine the best way of ensuring the SqlCacheDependency subscription has been started prior to the calls in these interfaces.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typically what I have seen in the past would be a middle layer between the data/presentation tiers that implement caching for the specific cache store.

[This article](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/caching-data-in-the-architecture-vb) on the asp.net site shows a bit of an overview of the architecture that I've seen in the past.

The biggest thing here is that you are right on target in that your options are not the same for each of the individual targets, therefore, trying to get something that would work across the board will prove to be a challenging prospect and most likely would result in using less than perfect methods to get a compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Add a caching layer.

Either you implement caching in each different data layer implementation, or you can save a lot of work and just implement the caching in a separate layer above the data layer, so you only have to do it once. This has the added benefit that you would be caching your data transfer objects, whereas if you put the caching in th DL you might have made the mistake of caching the raw data, which means you'd be translating it to DTO's every time you acess the cache.

An important aim is to have the caching layer present excactly the same interface as the regualar uncached data layer. If you can do that, then caching becomes optional- the cache just looks like any other DL implementation - and the upper layers have no knowledge of it. This can be tricky but it the payoff is good.

So:

[various DL implementaitons] - [DL interface] - [caching layer] - [DL interface] - [higher layers]